# Results on frames or Riesz basis in Hilbert spaces

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $A \subset B$ be bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose that we have $\{x_k\}$ being a Riesz basis in either $L^2(A)$ or $L^2(B)$. Can we say that it is a Riesz basis in the other space?

To be a Riesz basis $\{x_k\}$ must be complete. I think completeness would work like this right? If $A \subset B$ and $\{x_k\}$ is complete in $L^2(B)$, then $\{x_k\}$ is complete in $L^2(A)$. Is there any result like this for Riesz basis though?